# how to rotate scanner loop animation to horizontal

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS style that has an animation that sort of scans across a line with a loop over and over again. What I was trying to do is I have a different line but this one is horizontal but I can't figure out how to rotate the scanner to loop it horizontally. My current code is attached below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

code

```css
.vl {
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 4.7%;
            top: 0;
            background-color: aqua;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px aqua;
            width: 2.5px;
            height: calc(100% - 20px);
            border-radius: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    
        hr.h1 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 0px;
            background-color: aqua;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px aqua;
            width: 100%;
            height: calc(100% - 20px);
            border-radius: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    
        .scanner {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: white;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation: scanner-loop 3s ease-in-out infinite;
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
            height: 50%;
        }

        .scanner1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: white;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation: scanner-loop 3s ease-in-out infinite;
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
            height: 50%;
        }
    
    
        @keyframes scanner-loop {
            0% {
                top: 0;
            }
    
            50% {
                top: 100%;
            }
    
            100% {
                top: 0;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="vl">
<div class="scanner"></div>
</div>
<hr class="h1">
<div class="scanner1"></div>
</hr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with your animation. Keep seperate animation for horizontal and vertical.

In the horizontal animation use direction as `to right` also the `keyframes` should go from left to right

Please find a working example.

```css
/* Vertical animation section*/
.vl {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4.7%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px aqua;
  width: 2.5px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

hr.h1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: aqua;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px aqua;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scanner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: scanner-loop 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  background: linear-gradient(
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
  );
  height: 50%;
}

@keyframes scanner-loop {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }

  50% {
    top: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}

/* Horizontal animation section*/
.vh {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.7%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px aqua;
  height: 2.5px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scanner-h {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: scanner-horizontal-loop 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
  );
}

@keyframes scanner-horizontal-loop {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }

  50% {
    left: 0;
  }

  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Vertical -->
<div class="vl">
  <div class="scanner"></div>
</div>

<!-- Horizontal -->
<div class="vh">
  <div class="scanner-h"></div>
</div>
```